# Ruby if ... any? ... include? syntax

Tags: ruby

I need to check if any elements of a large (60,000+ elements) array are present in a long string of text. My current code looks like this:

```
if $TARGET_PARTLIST.any? { |target_pn| pdf_content_string.include? target_pn }
  self.last_match_code = target_pn
  self.is_a_match = true
end
```

I get a syntax error `undefined local variable or method target_pn`.

Could someone let me know the correct syntax to use for this block of code? Also, if anyone knows of a quicker way to do this, I'm all ears!

Comment: Turn the string into an array and then do a set intersection.

Comment: Interesting naming schema. What is `$TARGET_PARTLIST` a global constant?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. I don't get a syntax error. What is the *precise* syntax error you are getting?

Comment: For him, `target_pn` is undefined in the if block because it is scoped inside the `any?` block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, all your syntax is correct, you've just got a logic error. While `target_pn` is defined (as a parameter) inside the block passed to `any?`, it is not defined in the block of the `if` statement because the scope of the `any?`-block ends with the closing curly brace, and target_pn is not available outside its scope. A correct (and more idiomatic) version of your code would look like this:

```
self.is_a_match = $TARGET_PARTLIST.any? do |target_pn| 
  included = pdf_content_string.include? target_pn
  self.last_match_code = target_pn if included
  included
end
```

Alternately, as jvillian so kindly suggests, one could turn the string into an array of words, then do an intersection and see if the resulting set is nonempty. Like this:

```
self.is_a_match = !($TARGET_PARTLIST & 
                    pdf_content_string.gsub(/[^A-Za-z ]/,"")
                                      .split).empty?
```

Unfortunately, this approach loses `self.last_match_code`. As a note, pointed out by Sergio, if you're dealing with non-English languages, the above regex will have to be changed.

Hope that helps!

Comment: My pleasure! It's always good to see people still using Ruby.

Comment: Finding all words common to both the array and string is probably an inefficient way of determining if there is at least one match.You may want to use `split` rather than `split(' ')` in case there are two spaces in a row. See [String#split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-split). Alternatively, you could write `"how now, brown cow?".scan(/[[:alpha:]]+/) #=> ["how", "now", "brown", "cow"]`.

Comment: Your first snippet works incorrectly. That `.include?` is ignored. And the loop wrongly detects the first truthy `target_pn` as a match.

Comment: Tip: instead of `!a.empty?`, one can use `a.present?` (from activesupport, but this question is tagged `rails` anyway)

Comment: Hint: detecting words with `/A-Za-z/` won't work for most languages on earth, since every language except English (and Latin) has chars outside of that range (_citation needed_).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I do realize that, but I assumed (until further notice) that this was in English. Furthermore, I'm not in the business of providing ready-made answers. I'm assuming that if he requires something different with the second answer, he'll change it.

Comment: @ChristopherDumas: yes, not providing ready-made answers is totally fine. It's just that I've seen people totally oblivious to the presence of unicode. Thought a friendly hint wouldn't hurt :)

Comment: True. I've already put your warning (credited to you) in the updated answer. (:

Answer (score 2):

You should use [Enumerable#find](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) rather than [Enumerable#any?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F).

```
found = $TARGET_PARTLIST.find { |target_pn| pdf_content_string.include? target_pn }
if found
  self.last_match_code = found
  self.is_a_match = true
end
```

Note this does not ensure that the string contains a word that is an element of `$TARGET_PARTLIST`. For example, if `$TARGET_PARTLIST` contains the word "able", that string will be found in the string, "Are you comfortable?". If you only want to match words, you could do the following.

```
found = $TARGET_PARTLIST.find { |target_pn| pdf_content_string[/\b#{target_pn}\b/] }
```

Note this uses the method [String#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D).

`\b` is a *word break* in the regular expression, meaning that the first (last) character of the matched cannot be preceded (followed) by a word character (a letter, digit or underscore).

If speed is important it may be faster to use the following.

```
found = $TARGET_PARTLIST.find { |target_pn|
  pdf_content_string.include?(target_on) && pdf_content_string[/\b#{target_pn}\b/] }
```

Comment: "You don't need self." - One absolutely __does__ need self here. If `last_match_code` and `is_a_match` are methods, that is. Which they are, we can be relatively sure. Otherwise, there'd be another error message in the question.

Comment: I meant methods `last_match_code=` and `is_a_match=`, of course.

Comment: @Thanks, Sergio. I didn't read that carefully enough. I made the correction. Readers: to elaborate a bit, without `self.`,  `last_match_code` and `is_a_match` would be treated as local variables.

Answer (score 0):

A probably more performant way would be to move all this into native code by letting Regexp search for it.

```
# needed only once
TARGET_PARTLIST_RE = Regexp.new("\\b(?:#{$TARGET_PARTLIST.sort.map { |pl| Regexp.escape(pl) }.join('|')})\\b")

# to check
self.last_match_code = pdf_content_string[TARGET_PARTLIST_RE]
self.is_a_match = !self.last_match_code.nil?
```

A much more performant way would be to build a prefix tree and create the regexp using the prefix tree (this optimises the regexp lookup), but this is a bit more work :)